# birt report viewer how to show all results on same page

Tags: birt

I have a report with a large number of rows displaying from a data set. When I preview the report in the BIRT report viewer from the eclipse report designer (during my development) it allows me to scroll and see all the rows in the report without having to skip pages.

However when I see the same report in the Birt report viewer from my web application (java), the report viewer only shows about 50 rows per page and then I have to click on the next page button which is not what I want.

Using the report designer I have set the page break interval to 200 and avoid Before, After and Inside but still in my web application it doesn't show all the results in the same page like it does in eclipse.

Can someone help me with what setting I am missing to show all the results on the same page please. Here is how I embedd my report viewer into my jsp....

```
                <birt:viewer 
                    id="birtViewer" 
                    reportDesign="resources/reports/${reportName}.rptdesign"
                    pattern="frameset"
                    format="html"
                    height="600"
                    width="900"
                    title="${reportTitle}"
                    isHostPage="false">
                    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${reportParams}">                                                     
                        <birt:param name="${entry.key}" value="${entry.value}"/>                            
                    </c:forEach>                        
                </birt:viewer>
```

Comment: What version of BIRT do you use? This behavior with pagebreak interval keeps changing between 3.7, 4.2 and 4.3.

Comment: I am using version 3.7

Comment: Did you try to set the pagebreak interval of the table to 0? A value of 0 means the table should not be paginated, at least in html format.  it should work with v3.7

Comment: Hi, yes I tried this today. I also set the three available options to avoid. But still there is pagination. After some playing around I noticed that when I preview the report in eclipse using the web viewer I can reproduce the problem( I.e. The report is paginated). I had a look at the master page to see if there was anything I could set to avoid the page break but it didn't look like it. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem seems to be related to the height of the masterpage. When a layout of a report is set to "fixed" (see picture below), the masterpage has priority on the value of the pagebreak interval. Most of the time this height is set to 11 inch or something like that, this is why there are still pagebreaks even if we set a very large interval.

If we set a layout to "Auto", this time pagebreak interval is taken into consideration (at least in html format).

[image]

Comment: thank you. This worked for me 100%. All the books I have read tell you about the page breaks option but not to change to Auto Layout. I'm sure this post will help others.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the number of contents for the page in **Page Break Interval** as shown in the image.

[image]